# what are the performance effect on transitioning all elements for responsive design?

Tags: css, performance, transition

I want a smooth transition when the viewport resizes, so i added transition to all the elements

```
*{transition:all .5s}
```

is it bad, i mean does it have any adverse effect on performance?

Comment: css tends to be quite fast, especially now that many browsers have hardware acceleration built in. If you're using javascript to change classes and stuff often then it will of course slow down but that's different...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot tell exactly; but it could be very bad for older smartphones and tablets. What about you try it with your code and look in Webkit's/Blinks' developer tools. Depending on the implementation there could be optimizations like Apple's Quartz Extreme to deal with that... But in general CSS is quiet fast. And as your code should not trigger reflows there is no danger from race conditions as well.

Answer (score 2):

The only time a performance issue will occur is if you are changing the actual elements or adding media elements. I think that transition should be fine just remember vendor prefixes to ensure cross-browser compatibility.